# How to get around SlowDown Errors with AWS S3 put object

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to access a file and update it in S3 with boto but continue to get slowdown errors even after pausing in between requests as per code below. How do I get around this ?

```
body = b'Here we have some more data'
s3.put_object(Body=body,Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
time.sleep(10)
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
time.sleep(10)
print(response["Body"].read().decode('utf-8'))
currFile = response["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')
newFile = currFile + "\n" + "New Stuff!!!"
newFileB = newFile.encode('utf-8')
time.sleep(60)
s3.put_object(Body=newFileB,Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
time.sleep(10)
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
print(response["Body"].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Here is the error :

```
Details
The area below shows the result returned by your function execution.
{
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (SlowDown) when calling the PutObject operation (reached max retries: 4): Please reduce your request rate.",
"errorType": "ClientError",
"stackTrace": [
[
"/var/task/lambda_function.py",
43,
"lambda_handler",
"raise e"
],
[
"/var/task/lambda_function.py",
20,
"lambda_handler",
"s3.put_object(Body=body,Bucket=bucket, Key=key)"
],
[
"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
314,
"_api_call",
"return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
],
[
"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
612,
"_make_api_call",
"raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)"
]
]
}
```

Comment: How long has this been happening?  How old is the bucket?  What is your current request rate (requests per second)?

Comment: The bucket is a few days old. Where's the best place to track requests per second ?

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem and I am not sure why it happens, but it is the sort of thing that production code has to deal with all the time. The solution is to just keep trying and not give up for up to quite a while. Upon a failure, the loop starts with a delay of 1 second and then it increases that in each loop by a second (delay_incr), finally timing out a max_delay of 30 sec per loop, which is actually a max total 7.5 minutes, when it finally gives up. Of course you can twiddle the timings. This has been successful for me so far.

I have to do a similar thing even for a NAS file server where I have to wait for a while to read files at times.

````
def put_s3_core(bucket: str, key: str, strobj: Any, content_type: str=''):  
    """ write strobj to s3 bucket, key
        content_type can be:
            binary/octet-stream (default)
            text/plain
            text/html
            text/csv
            image/png
            image/tiff
            application/pdf
            application/zip
            
    """
    if not strobj: 
        return
    
    delay = 0.5     # initial delay
    delay_incr = .5 # additional delay in each loop
    max_delay = 5   # max delay of one loop. Total delay is (max_delay**2)/2
    error_data = None
    
    while delay < max_delay:   
        try:
            s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
            request_obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
            if content_type:
                request_obj.put(Body=strobj, ContentType=content_type)        
            else:
                request_obj.put(Body=strobj)
            break               
                
        except ClientError as err:
            code = err.response.get('Error',{}).get('Code', '')
            if code in ['NoSuchBucket']:
                print(f"Error: {code}. Check s3path: s3://{bucket}/{key}")
                raise err
            time.sleep(delay)
            delay += delay_incr
            error_data = err
    else:
        print(f"{logs.prog_loc()} Timeout encountered trying to write to s3://{bucket}/{key} strobj of len {len(strobj):,} bytes Error {error_data}")
        logs.error_beep()
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace() #perm
        
        raise TimeoutError

    ```
````

Comment: It would be better if this code actually checked the error was caused by `SlowDown` from the server rather than retry and slowing down on any `ClientError`

Comment: I edited the code because I also found that when the file does not exist, s3 gives a Client error "NoSuchBucket", so this gives an instant error.